# Hola, estoy estudiando java, tengo un trabajo final que entregar pero me trabe en los formularios. no me funciona el evento "click"

Tags: javascript

estoy estudiando javascript asique no se mucho al respecto, estoy haciendo un trabajo que es con formularios de sing in y sing up, se supone que las clases 'active' en los formularios deberian hacer que muestren/oculten alternandose uno de otro. no se si me explico. saque la idea de youtube pero no pude hacer que me funcione.no me responden los botones, ni el hover de los botones, y en la consola no me aparece nada si le hago click, espero me puedan orientar, gracias!
por que necesito aprobarrrr. y si me recomiendan alguna web donde pueda sacar proyectos para practicar, les agradezco mas todavia!

```
<body>
    <div class="container-form sing-up">
        <div class="welcome-back">
            <div class="mensaje">
                <h2>¡Bienvenido!</h2>
                <p>Si ya tienes una cuenta, por favor inicia sesion aqui</p>
                <button class="sing-up-btn">Iniciar sesion</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form class="formulario">
            <h2 class="crearCuenta">Crear cuenta</h2>
            <div class="iconos">
                <div class="border-icon">
                    <i class="bi bi-instagram"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="border-icon">
                    <i class="bi bi-facebook"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="border-icon">
                    <i class="bi bi-twitter"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="cuenta-gratis">Crear una cuenta gratis</p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre" autocomplete="nombre">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" autocomplete="email">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="Contraseña" autocomplete="current-password">
            <input type="button" value="Registrarse">
        </form>
    </div>
        <div class="container-form sing-in">
            <form class="formulario">
                <h2 class="crearCuenta">Iniciar sesion</h2>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <div class="border-icon">
                        <i class="bi bi-instagram"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="border-icon">
                        <i class="bi bi-facebook"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="border-icon">
                        <i class="bi bi-twitter"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <p class="cuenta-gratis">¿Aun no tienes cuenta?</p>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" autocomplete="email">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="Contraseña" autocomplete="current-password">
                    <input type="button" value="Iniciar Sesion">
            </form>
            <div class="welcome-back">
                <div class="mensaje">
                    <h2>¡Bienvenido de nuevo!</h2>
                    <p>Si aun no tienes una cuenta, por favor registrese aqui</p>
                    <button class="sing-up-btn">Iniciar sesion</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Incluye jQuery y Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    const $btnSingIn = document.querySelector('.sing-in-btn'),
    $btnSingUp = document.querySelector('.sing-up-btn'),
    $singUp = document.querySelector('.sing-up'),
    $singIn = document.querySelector('.sing-in');

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target === $btnSingIn || e.target === $btnSingUp) {
        $singIn.classList.toggle('active')
        $singUp.classList.toggle('active')
    }
});
```

Comment: En realidad sí están funcionando los botones. Si inspeccionás el DOM (F12 en el navegador, al menos en Firefox y Chromium) vas a ver que cada vez que estás haciendo click agrega o quita la clase _active_. No está demás que revises la documentación de Bootstrap: la clase _active_ no necesariamente muestra u oculta cosas. Por otra parte, jQuery ya no es necesario desde la versión 5 de Bootstrap. Y por cierto, no mostraste si importás el CSS de Bootstrap en el head :)

Comment: Pequeña observación extra: _sing_ no es lo mismo que _sign_. _Sing_ significa _cantar_...

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por responder!! si si lo tengo importado, tenes razon tengo mal escrito sign no me habia dado cuenta, y la clase active no es de javascript tambien? o ya mexcle todo jajajajaja yo probe con chrome y firefox y no me aparece nada.. que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: java != javascript... agrega un console log antes de cambiar el active, a ver que pasa...